# class* argument displayed as <error-type>*

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have this class:

```
#pragma once
#include <thread>
#include "Game.h"

class CPhysics {
    CGame *mGame;
    //[...]

public:
    CPhysics(CGame *game);

    //[...]
};
```

I pass the `CGame` instance to the constructor of `CPhysics` like this:

```
#include "Game.h"

CGame::CGame() {
    //[...]
    mPhysics = new CPhysics(this);
}
```

But the compiler does not know what to do and gives me `<error-type> *game` instead of `CGame *game`. I want to pass a pointer to the `CGame` instance. What will be sent if I remove the asterisk? I'm a little bit confused.

[image: The error]

**EDIT:** The actual error is as follows: Instead of `CPhysics(CGame *game)` constructor it wants to use `CPhysics(CPhysics &&)`. But `CGame *const` cannot and shall not be converted to `const CPhysics &`. I'm guessing this is due to the error-type.

Comment: What is the actual error when you compile. Also i suspect you have a circular dependency loop.

Comment: This text is coming from your IDE, not your compiler

Comment: Does `Game.h` include `Physics.h` by any chance? I'd guess `CGame` isn't [yet] declared. You might want to use a forward declaration (or break the cyclic dependency).

Comment: _"I pass the CGame instance"_ Nope, no you don't!

Comment: I added some information about the actual error.

@DietmarKühl Yes, `Game.h` includes `Physics.h` and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `mPhysics = new CPhysics(this);`
you need define a construct function without any parameters for `CPhysics` and redefine a new assign constructor for `Cpysics`.

Comment: If the constructor has no parameters, how would `this` get passed? He's calling it in a `CGame` method, so `this` is a `CGame*`, not a `CPhysics*`.